# Storing comma separated entries in a list and print them using pgfkeys, pgffor, etoolbox

Tags: macros, lists, pgfkeys, pgffor

**Problem Statement**

I want to store several keywords in a list, then print all items inside the list separated by commas, but the last item should also be separated by ", and ...". For example, this is what I want:

- add "fluid", "computation", and "numerical methods"
- add "turbulence"
- add "stability analysis" and "convergence check"
- print: "fluid, computation, numerical methods, turbulence, stability analysis, and convergence check"

**My Attempt**

After looking around Stack Exchange and using ChatGPT, I wrote the following:

```
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{numKeywords}
\def\topicList{}

\newcommand{\addTopic}[1]{%
  \pgfkeys{/topic, #1}%
  \ifx\keyword\empty
    % do nothing
  \else
    \foreach \entry in \keyword {%
      \stepcounter{numKeywords}\listadd\topicList{\entry}
    }
  \fi
}

\pgfkeys{
  /topic/.is family,
  /topic,
  keyword/.store in = \keyword,
}

\newcommand{\printTopics}{%
  \renewcommand{\do}[1]{%
    \ifnumequal{\value{numKeywords}}{1}{%
      and ##1
    }{%
      \addtocounter{numKeywords}{-1}{##1},%
    }
  \dolistloop{\topicList}
}
```

My idea is to use \numKeywords to count the number of keywords in the list. Then when there's only one keyword left I print the word "and" in addition to the comma.

Usage in main document:

```
\documentclass{article}

% preamble
% ...

\begin{document}

\addTopic{%
  keyword={fluid, computation, numerical methods}
}

\addTopic{%
  keyword={turbulence}
}

\addTopic{%
  keyword={stability analysis, convergence check}
}

\printTopic

\end{document}
```

This does not work. I suspect it's because of expansion or non-expansion of the \entry in the following line:

```
\stepcounter{numKeywords}\listadd\topicList{\entry}
```

but I couldn't troubleshoot or figure out how to fix it. Any idea on what I should try?

Thanks!

Comment: For clists I would recomment use l3 functions.  `\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_set:Nn\l_tmpa_clist{keyword1, keyword2, keyword3}
\clist_use:Nnnn\l_tmpa_clist{,}{,}{~and~}
\ExplSyntaxOff `

Comment: Even if you need them to be in PGF type keys can still be incorporated. xdoc interface3 for manual and look up on clists.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution. The l3 layer can co-exist with PGF, except if you use in the code polar coordinates. Here is a solution. It takes an afternoon to get into it and will save you hours and days as you progress with your documents.

```
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/701345/storing-comma-separated-entries-in-a-list-and-print-them-using-pgfkeys-pgffor
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\pkgfamilyname{rheza}
\cs_if_exist:NTF \kvset{\ERROR} 
  {
    \pgfkeys{/\pkgfamilyname/.is~family} 
    \def\kvset{\pgfqkeys{/\pkgfamilyname}} 
  }
% Initialize list with some values      
\clist_set:Nn\l_tmpa_clist{keyword1, keyword2, keyword3}
% Define keys
\kvset{list~add/.code =\clist_put_right:Nn\l_tmpa_clist{#1}} 
\kvset{list~print/.code= \clist_use:Nnnn\l_tmpa_clist{,}{,}{~and~}}
% Use a key to add keywords
\kvset{list~add=keyword4}
\kvset{list~add=keyword5}
\clist_use:Nnnn\l_tmpa_clist{,}{,}{~and~}\par
\ExplSyntaxOff
\kvset{list print}
\end{document}
```

Comment: 'It take an afternoon to get into it ...'. I suspect this says more about your existing expertise than it does about the difficulty or otherwise of the material ;). But why use kv rather than l3 keys, if you're using l3 clists? Also, I've never heard of `xdoc` (which you mentioned in a comment. `which xdoc` returns no results on my machine.